# More elegant way to write a code

Tags: matlab

Is there a more elegant way to write this simple code ? The aim is to avoid loops.
I tried with `repmat` for indexes but it didnt work

```
for j=1:size(C,1);
    for k=1:size(C,2)
        C(j,k)=sum(sum(A([1:j],[1:k]).*B([j:-1:1],[k:-1:1])));
    end
end
```

---

**EDIT**

I modified the code

```
j=1:size(C,1);
k=1:size(C,2);
B2=rot90(B,2);
C(j,k)=sum(sum(A(1:j,1:k).*B2(end+1-j:end,end+1-k:end)));
```

It's normal that I have the same value on all the matrix C ?

P.S: I understood that conv2 is the more performant function but I just want to understand where is the problem (why (j, k) doesn't vary) and what's the solution (without loop)

Thank you

Comment: Try posting this in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of Stackoverflow.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @VaheTshitoyan I am trying to calculate the convolution. Normally, the couple (j,k) has to vary on all the indexes of the matrix 3x3 but It seems that it doesn't vary ( it shows only the result of (j,k)=(1,1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this just what [conv2(A,B,'same')](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html) does?

***EDIT***

I tested it. It's not exactly the same. But upper left part of `conv(A,B)` is equal to your `C`.